# Function with `cond` and `and` in Racket

Tags: function, conditional-statements, racket

I am having hard time understanding `and` + `cond` functions in Racket. Why are the following two functions different from each other?

Function *a*:

```
(define (test? function)
  (and (list? function) (>= (length function) 1)))
```

Function *b*:

```
(define (test?function )
 (cond [(and (list? function))
         (>= (length function) 1) ]))
```

In my understanding this basically means,

- `(if (list? function)` return true;
- `(if (>= (length function) 1)` return true;

which is pretty much same as the function *a*. Is my understanding wrong here?

I cannot understand how they are different from each other. Please explain. Is it not possible to write function *a* with `cond` / `if` ?

Comment: why do you think the two are different? do you have evidence for that?

Answer (score 3):

First, `cond` and `and` are not functions, they are "special forms" (implemented as macros). The syntax of a `cond` expression is different from the syntax of a function call. The syntax of an `and` expression is the same as for a function call, but `and` does not necessarily evaluate all of its arguments.

Here's one way of rewriting your `test?` function using `cond`. (I've also renamed the argument from `function` to `x`, because it doesn't seem to be acting like a function.)

```
(define (test? x)
  (cond [(and (list? x) (>= (length x) 1))
         #t]
        [else
         #f]))
```

In general, whenever you have a boolean expression `expr` you can replace it with `(cond [expr #t] [else #f])` or `(if expr #t #f)`. But there's usually no point in doing that.

Here's another way of writing the function: `(and condition1 condition2)` means the same thing as `(cond [condition1 condition2] [else #f])`, so you could write the function like this:

```
(define (test? x)
  (cond [(list? x)
         (>= (length x) 1)]
        [else
         #f]))
```

Generally, though, the original version of the function would be considered best:

```
(define (test? x) (and (list? x) (>= (length x) 1)))
```

Comment: My answer originally had a typo: I left off the second argument to `>=`, so the function wasn't actually checking the length was at least 1. I've edited my answer to fix it.